# Javascript getting Datatable column names

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

i am using Google charts to build stacked bar charts, created a listener to handler onclick event.
there are three columns (site Name, Completed and Incomplete).
 i want listener to capture whether user clicked 
completed or incomplete, when i click on the first row data this is what i am getting.
i know in my getColumnLabel method i am getting all column names but i want that to be captured based upon what user clicked

```
//my datatable

        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data2.addColumn('string', 'Site Name');

        data2.addColumn('number', 'Completed');

        data2.addColumn('number', 'Incomplete');

        data2.addRows([
                        [Site1, 12, 7],
                        [Site2, 10, 9],
                        [Site3, 15, 4],
                        [Site4, 10, 5]
                        ]);


//listener function 
    var selection = ChartName.getSelection();

            var row = selection[0].row;

            data2.getColumnLabel(0);  //givesme: SiteName

            data2.getColumnLabel(1); //givesme: Completed   

    data2.getColumnLabel(2) //givesme: Incompleted

            data2.getValue(row, 0); //givesme: Site1

            data2.getValue(row, 1); //givesme: 12
```

Comment: Does `selection[0]` have a column attribute?  [reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visgetselection)

Comment: selection[0] is it not the selected row? not too sure.

Comment: selection[0] is it not the selected row? not too sure. i want to get the column name that the user has selected data from so in my example i want to know if those numbers are coming from completed or incomplete so instead of saying  data2.getColumnLabel(1) for completed and data2.getColumnLabel(2) for Incomplete it should be based upon the index of the column

Comment: A word of caution: before you call `selection[0].row`, you should check to make sure that an element was selected in the first place, because deselecting an element also fires the `select` event, so `selection` might be a zero-length array.

Comment: your question is irrelevant to my problem, but your code helped me solve my problem!! thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i have managed to find the solution, for reference if anyone is interested

var ColName1 = data2.getColumnLabel(selection.column);

so selection.column property gives you the selected column from the datatable