# Retrieve value column header google visualisation

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to retrieve the value of the column header when a user clicks on 1 of the bars of the chart. A report should be generated with the parameters I retrieve from the chart. This is what I have so far:

```
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', '2014', '2015'],
      ['Jan', 0, 200.00],
      ['Feb', 0, 400.00],
      ['Mar', 0, 700.00],
      ['Apr', 0, 100.00],
      ['May', 400.00, 900.00],
      ['Jun', 1100.00, 0],
      ['Jul', 3400.00, 0],
      ['Aug', 2500.00, 0],
      ['Sep', 2450.00, 0],
      ['Oct', 3170.00, 0],
      ['Nov', 2500.00, 0],
      ['Dec', 1979.00, 0]
              ]);


      var options = {
          title: 'Raised'
        };
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div_month'));


        function selectHandler() {
            var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
            if (selectedItem) {
                var month = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                var year = data.getValue(0, selectedItem.column);
                window.location = 'report.php?submit=Submit&year=' + year + '&month=' + month;

            }

        }  
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);   



      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I am able to retrieve the month parameter, but not the year.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537784/javascript-getting-datatable-column-names

Answer (score 1):

Reading about google chart tables [at their API page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#methods) it says that

```
getSelection() - Standard getSelection implementation. 
                 Selection elements are all row elements. 
                 Can return more than one selected row.
```

So getSelection() doesn't select any column, and therefore `var year = data.getValue(0, selectedItem.column);`won't work.

Why it is like this I don't know, as the getSelection() returns both a row and a column, but the column is always null (thought it hasn't always been like this, there are loads of examples where people show how it works, but they are all broken today).

I have seen an approach that uses standard javascript (or was it jQuery?) to detect which column is clicked (**clicked**, not selected) by listening for mouseclicks on tds and getting the column property that way, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: did nobody has to do this before?