# Populating data dynamically from JSON in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
    My JSON data: 

    {"price":1.0,"bookName":"ABC","time":"10:0"},{"price":1.0,"bookName"
    :"DEF","time":"10:0"},{"price":1.0,"bookName":"ERT","time":"10:0"},{"price":1.0,"bookName":"JKL","time":"10:0"},{"price":0.25,"bookName":"ABC","time":"10:05"},{"price"
    :0.25,"bookName":"DEF","time":"10:05"},{"price":0.25,"bookName"
    :"ERT","time":"10:05"},{"price":0.25,"bookName":"JKL","time":"10:05"}

    JS Code: 

    WHen i hardcode the value like below then i am able to display the chart.

    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     function drawChart(){

      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'ERT', 'JKL'],
          ['10:0',  1.0,      0.25,         0.25,             1.0          ],
          ['10:0',  1.0,      1.0,        1.0,             1.0          ],
          ['10:0',  0.25,      0.25,        0.25,             0.25],
          ['10:0',  1.0,      0.25,        0.25,             0.25],
          ['10:05',  1.0,      0.25,         1.0,             0.25],
          ['10:05',  0.25,     1.0,         0.25,             1.0],
          ['10:05',  0.25,      0.25,         0.25,             0.25],
          ['10:05',  0.25,      0.25,         0.25,             0.25],
             ]);

    I would like to know how to create the data like above dynamically using JSON object. I have tried the below code so far.
```

Here the problem is i have to generate the columns also dynamically i.e from JSON object. bookname will always be the 4 mentioned, just their price will vary at different time.

resultObj is actual JSON object name im getting from backend.

I would like to know how to proceed further for creating the rows data.

Please guide me. I can add more details if required for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format on your JSON, google charts has a specific layout they use to recieve data through, read more [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam).

Your data would have to look like:

```
{
  cols:[{label:'Bookmark', type:'string'}, 
        {label:'Price', type:'number'}, 
        {label:'time', type:'number'}
       ],
  rows:[{c:[{v:'ABC'}, {v:1.0}, {v:10.0}]},
         c:[{v:'DEF'}, {v:1.0}, {v:10.0}]},
       }]
}
```

So you have to dynamically arrange them like this, to be able to pass the whole JSON to your chart.

I made a small [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/bw4nu85y/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me explain you, what i want as a final output. I want to plot a combochart on X-axis will be the time and on Y-axis will be the price of the books. So for eg: at 10:00AM for book ABC,price is 10. So I have to create 1 column for Time and other columns for book names. Then i want to populate this columns programtically as i have mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Your problem is still the format of your JSON. You need to follow the format that google has specified in the link I provided.

I remade my earlier fiddle to complete what you wish, look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/bw4nu85y/1/).

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks. Using the reference, i was able to draw the chart dynamically. Now, my next requirement is, whenever you click on the bar, say ABC then I have to drilldown and create another chart with some different details. Now, could you please let me know how i can get the actual value "ABC" in a new function when you click on that bar. As using this bookname value i have to fire another call to perform the data. I have so far tried the given examples of select event and then try to get the value, but it returns me row value i.e time or price value, but i couldnt get column value "ABC"

Comment: thanks, i got the solution from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537784/javascript-getting-datatable-column-names